# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function when using rownum

Tags: sql, oracle

I get  `ORA-00937` error when firing the below query.

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT streetid,
    roadid,
    LISTAGG(longitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sequence_number) long_agg ,
    LISTAGG(latitude ,',')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sequence_number) lat_agg ,
    rownum r
  FROM linkstable
  WHERE areaid = 100
 group by strretid,roadid )
WHERE r > 100 AND r < 200;
```

**Error:**

```
 ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from Gordon's solution, a workaround for using rownum

```
WITH street_list as
(
 SELECT streetid,
    roadid,
    LISTAGG(longitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sequence_number) long_agg ,
    LISTAGG(latitude ,',')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY sequence_number) lat_agg ,
  FROM linkstable
  WHERE areaid = 100
 group by strretid,roadid 
),
street_list_numbered as
(
  SELECT rownum r,streetid,roadid, long_agg,lat_agg 
 FROM street_list
)
SELECT * FROM street_list_numbered
WHERE r > 100  and r <  200;
```

Comment: Thank you @OracleUser and GordonLinoff :)

Answer (score 3):

This is your query:

```
select * 
from (select t.*, rownum as r
      from (select streetid, roadid,
                   LISTAGG(longitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence_number) as long_agg ,  
                   LISTAGG(latitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence_number) as lat_agg 
           from  linkstable
           where areaid = 100
          ) t
     ) t
where r > 100  and r <  200;
```

You are using `LISTAGG()` as an aggregation function, but there is no `group by`.  Hence, all the other columns are invalid because they are not arguments to aggregation functions.  Perhaps you intend:

```
select * 
from (select streetid, roadid,
             LISTAGG(longitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence_number) as long_agg ,  
             LISTAGG(latitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence_number) as lat_agg ,
             rownum r 
      from  linkstable
      where areaid = 100
      group by streetid, roadid
     )
where r > 100  and r <  200;
```

Comment: Not only that, the subquery needs an alias.

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . Oracle does not require aliases on subqueries.

Comment: Who knew?  Apparently, everone but me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes I missed adding a group by inside. I dont get your point here. Now I made sure to use aggregation with group by. Still dont find the hunch.

Comment: select * from (select rownum r,tile_id,link_id,LISTAGG(longitude ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence_number) long_agg , LISTAGG(latitude ,',')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sequence_number) lat_agg FROM  rtg_shape_points_base_links  
where region_component_id = 184 group by tile_id,link_id,rownum ) where r > 100 and r < 200; . This query doesnt give me the list aggregate value for long_agg and lat_agg. Instead I need the list. 
@OracleUser: Yes that's the point. I need to have rownum in.

Comment: @Vignesh . . . This surprises me.  I've used Oracle for a long, long time.  I guess I never put `rownum` in a `group by` query before; it does indeed produce an error.  The work-around is easy, just an additional subquery or using the `row_number()` function.  By the way, you should always include an `order by`, because the results may differ from one query run to the next.